# What kinds of indexes would you create to speed up queries to this table?

Tags: database, indexing

I had a question that I could really use someone's help with. 
So suppose I have the following huge table with about one million rows:
ORDER (Order#, OrderDate, Customer#, OrderAmount, Product#, DiscountAmount, OrderStatus, OrderFullfillmentDate)

In this table, Order# is PK, and Customer# is a FK to the Customer Table and Product is a FK to the Product table. What kinds of indexes could I create to speed up queries to this table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you need to do with this table. 
1. Apply index on all fields
2. Pay attention on query because query are prepare relative to where close and you can ask in a query, that is not optimised, to load hole table in memory even the final result contain a few rows.
3. Create many tables with less fields (cols) instead few tables with many cols

I can help you if you can give me more detail and example how you extract data from this table. I am curios where is the unique Order_id and how you query a specific order number.
There are many methods to optimize tables, queries and quick output the results.

Comment: This is more of a general question. This was a question that was asked of me, but I wasn't sure on how to answer.